# How to generate facetted ggplot graph where each facet has ordered data?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, facet

I want to sort my factors (Condition, Parameter and SubjectID) by MeanWeight and plot MeanWeight against SubjectID such that when faceted by Condition and Parameter, MeanWeight appears in descending order. 
Here is my solution, which isn't giving me what I want:

```
dataSummary <- structure(list(SubjectID = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("s001", 
"s002", "s003", "s004"), class = "factor"), Condition = structure(c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "factor"), Parameter = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
3L), .Label = c("(Intercept)", "PrevCorr1", "PrevFail1"), class = "factor"), 
    MeanWeight = c(-0.389685536725783, 0.200987679398502, -0.808114314421089, 
    -0.10196105040707, 0.0274188815763494, 0.359978984195839, 
    -0.554583879312783, 0.643791202050396, -0.145042221940287, 
    -0.0144598460145723, -0.225804028997856, -0.928152539784374, 
    0.134025102103562, -0.267448309989731, -1.19980109795115, 
    0.0587152632631923, 0.0050656268880826, -0.156537446664213
    )), .Names = c("SubjectID", "Condition", "Parameter", "MeanWeight"
), row.names = c(NA, 18L), class = "data.frame")
## Order by three variables
orderWeights <- order(dataSummary$Condition, dataSummary$Parameter, dataSummary$SubjectID, -dataSummary$MeanWeight)
## Set factors to the new order. I expect this to sort for each facet when plotting, but it doesn't seem to work. 
conditionOrder <- dataSummary$Condition[orderWeights]
dataSummary$Condition <- factor(dataSummary$Condition, levels=conditionOrder)
paramOrder <- dataSummary$Parameter[orderWeights]
dataSummary$Parameter <- factor(dataSummary$Parameter, levels=paramOrder)
sbjOrder <- dataSummary$SubjectID[orderWeights]
dataSummary$SubjectID <- factor(dataSummary$SubjectID, levels=sbjOrder)
## Plot
ggplot(dataSummary, aes(x=MeanWeight, y=SubjectID)) + 
scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-3, 3)) + 
geom_vline(yintercept = 0.0, size = 0.1, colour = "#a9a9a9", linetype = "solid") + 
geom_segment(aes(yend=SubjectID), xend=0, colour="grey50") + 
geom_point(size=2) + 
facet_grid(Parameter~Condition, scales="free_y")
```

I tried a few other approaches, but they didn't work either:

```
dataSummary <- dataSummary[order(dataSummary$Condition, dataSummary$Parameter, dataSummary$SubjectID, -dataSummary$MeanWeight),]
```

or this one

```
dataSummary <- transform(dataSummary, SubjectID=reorder(Condition, Parameter, SubjectID, MeanWeight))
```

Comment: (1) Did you not notice all the warnings thrown by your code? (2) What you are attempting is not possible (using faceting). It would require different orderings of the y axis for each row of facets.

Comment: @joran, (1) I saw the warnings and ignored them after not quickly figuring out what they were telling me. (2) I was expecting "scales='free'" in facet_grid would let me have independent scales for each plot. Want to try converting y axis into continuous variable.

Comment: All free scales will do is allow the _ranges_ to vary. But faceting is , by definition, intended for when the scales are essentially the same. You're proposing entirely different orderings, hence entirely different scales. The only option I know of is to use grid.arrange as mentioned below.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can order your data and plot it. However, the labels no longer correspond to Subject ID's, but to the reordered subjects. If that is not what you want, you  cannot use faceting but have to plot the parts separately and use e.g.`grid.arrange`to combind the different plots.

```
require(plyr)
## Ordered data
datOrder <- ddply(dataSummary, c("Condition", "Parameter"), function(x){
  if (nrow(x)<=1) return(x)
  x$MeanWeight <- x$MeanWeight[order(x$MeanWeight)]
  x
})
## Plot
ggplot(datOrder, aes(x=MeanWeight, y=SubjectID)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(limits=c(-3, 3)) + 
  geom_vline(yintercept = 0.0, size = 0.1, colour = "#a9a9a9", linetype = "solid") + 
  geom_segment(aes(yend=SubjectID), xend=0, colour="grey50") + 
  geom_point(size=2) + 
  facet_grid(Parameter~Condition) +
  scale_y_discrete(name="Ordered subjects")
```

Comment: thanks @shadow. This is close to what I want. However, I also wanted to have SubjectID matching the order. I was hoping that setting "scales='free'" in facet_grid allows having independent axes for each plot, but it may not be the case for factors. I am now thinking to convert SubjectID from categorical to continuous variable and see if that would work with facet_grid